# Naming convention(or best practice) when loading is done for React state

Tags: reactjs, naming-conventions

I want to know the naming convention(or best practice) for loading is done,

For example, I load Modal popup and I need a state for indicating componentDidMount is done.

```js
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ onLoading: true })
    }
    render() {
       return (
           {this.state.onLoading && 
               <div> Show up after Loading </div> 
           }
       )
    }
```

My best idea is

1. onLoading
2. completeLoad

Is there any website for reference to this naming convention or Could you suggest any good practice?

Comment: I usually use `isLoading` and `isError`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste isLoading initialState is true and when didmount is done, then isLoading is false?

Comment: I would use this for something like a fetch request for an external API.  Start with isLoading true.  When the API fetch is done, set isLoading to false and also store the data.  ComponentDidMount should be almost instantaneous.  Having an isLoading state makes sense when you are dealing with something that is loaded asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a specific naming convention for this type of case. However, I've seen that most applications use `loading` or `isLoading`. `is` as a prefix for booleans is widely used so I recommend you to use it.

Comment: Could you add your scenario for `isLoading` value?

Comment: Since it's a boolean, some people often prefer to set it with the prefix ```is```, so it is more clear that it has two states (it either is or is not). Since you want to know whether IS loading or IS NOT loading, whenever the ```isLoading``` variable equals true, then you know it is loading. All in all, it's because is easier to understand for yourself and for other developers since its syntax is closer to normal communication. "It is loading".